# JRebel with web-fragments giving 404 errors after modification

Tags: java, servlet-3.0, jrebel

I have been trying to get JRebel to work with a web project which contains web fragments.  However, after I change the code and JRebel deploys the changes, the web application starts giving 404 errors for all pages and requests.

Can someone indicate what might be the issue please?

NB: I am using Tomcat 7.0.21 and maven

Comment: Did you report this at JRebel forums? jrebel.log could be helpful to debug the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bug in jrebel. You can solve it this way if you are using Eclipse:

Enter a space in your code, delete the space, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save your code. Then refresh your browser.

Sometimes it doesn't work. And you can try it again. Sometimes I try it for 4 times and it works.
I suggest you to use other software to help you to do this thing.